# Linux System Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program

Tags: linux

"fsck.ext2: Device or Resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdb"
"Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?"

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: did you forget to append a number for the partition you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of lsof run with root privileges? Are you trying to use the partition or the device, as you may get errors if you don't mount the proper partition...